# How to pass JSON data to a live URL in asp .net?

Tags: asp.net, json

I am trying to hit the URL and get the response message. But it is not returning anything.
 http://ip.jsontest.com/. 
I have posted my code.

```
function ShowAvailability() {
    alert("ShowAvailability:Start");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json, status) {
            if (status != "success") {
                alert("Error loading data");
                return;
            }
            log("Data loaded!");
        },
        error: function (result, status, err) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert('result: ' + result.responseText);
            alert('status: ' + status.responseText);
            alert(err.Message);
            alert("Error loading data");
            return;
        }
    });
    alert("ShowAvailability:End");
}
```

Comment: How do you want to fetch? In JavaScript, in C# code? Can you also show your code, which is easier to point the problem

Comment: nice space in : `url: ' h`

Comment: The above code returns data for me. Is there any JavaScript error?

Comment: @Kiran Hegde--Which data is returning? Can you plz post your code?

Comment: @Kiran Hegde- One more help please....How to pass data to URL through JSON so that my request will hit that URL. And return some response.

Comment: You have to use data: {} property of the ajax call to pass data to server. You can refer examples here. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Kiran Hegde-I have done like this.But it is not hitting to the given URL.What are the faults that the passed data will not hit the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57683/discussion-between-kiran-hegde-and-prb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not made any changes to your code. I have added alerting the retrieved json data. I get the ip address properly. Check the following code

```
function ShowAvailability() {
        alert("ShowAvailability:Start");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json, status) {

                if (status != "success") {
                    alert("Error loading data");
                    return;
                }
                else
                    alert(json.ip)
                log("Data loaded!");
            },
            error: function (result, status, err) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert('result: ' + result.responseText);
                alert('status: ' + status.responseText);
                alert(err.Message);
                alert("Error loading data");
                return;
            }
        });
        alert("ShowAvailability:End");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yes now showing.Thank you :). Actually i was trying to show in log("Data loaded!"); and thats why it was not showing anything.